# Which are the radio stations are compatible to radiotray?

Tags: streaming, gstreamer, internet-radio

I had some trouble in searching and adding radio stations to RadioTray. It will be extremely helpful if some one lists radio stations which work on RadioTray. Rock, hard rock, metal, traditional metal, symphonic metal, rap are my preferred genres but any others are welcome.

My focus is on stations which have been tried on RadioTray.

Also I would like Indian radio channels as I can't find any.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this?

Comment: @Seth Not really. I explored and found sites giving a `.pls` file which gives the URL on opening with text editor. However, that is not common for all. I needed to know if there was a simpler way than this, to get the actual streaming channel of any radio. As mentioned in the question, I get the most-listened-but-not-interesting channels. I wanted the rarer or browser-only ones if possible.

Comment: Hmm. What version of Ubuntu are you using? I'm guessing it's 12.04 since tray icons have since been made really limited.